Understanding exact sequences
Im reading "Introduction to Conmutative algebra" by Atiyah and Macdonald. They define a a sequence of $A$-modules and $A$-homomorfism, where $A$ is a abelian ring with identity and $0$ is the zero ring, as follow
$$\dots \longrightarrow M_{i-1}\overset{f_i}{\longrightarrow}M_i \overset{f_{i+1}}{\longrightarrow} M_{i+1}\longrightarrow \dots$$
Consecuently they define that the sequence is said to be exact at $M_{i}$ if Im($f_i$)=Ker($f_{i+1}$). The sequence is exact if is exact at each $M_{i}$. In particular,
$0 \longrightarrow M' \overset{f}{\longrightarrow}M$ is exact iff $f$ is inyective.
To prove this, we need that $0,\  M',\ M$ has to be exact. Then the sequence is missing $A$-modules? Since in order for the sequence to be exact at $M$, Im$f$=Ker( of what?). Thou it obvious that $$0 \longrightarrow M' \overset{f}{\longrightarrow}M\longrightarrow 0\longrightarrow 0\longrightarrow 0\dots$$
But the book never said so

No, not the image of $f$. Exactness at $M'$ means that the image of the first map (which is zero), is the kernel of $f$. Hence $ker(f)=0$, and $f$ is injective.

@DietrichBurde Okey, but if f is injective then the sequence is exact $M'$ just like you said. How i establish the exactness at $0$ and $M$?

You establish it the same way. The map $g$ left of $0$ is by convention also the zero map. So $im (g)=0=Ker(i)$, where $i$ is the map $0\rightarrow M'$. Done. Right of  $M$ is nothing, so we cannot apply the definition (there is no map anymore). What you wrote, $M\rightarrow 0$ is not correct. Therefore the book "never said so", rightly.

@DietrichBurde Thanks, so we cannot said nothing about M and thanks for the correction

There should be a definition of exactness of finite sequences of modules and homomorphisms, namely that the sequence is exact at each of the modules except the first and last. Similarly for one-way infinite sequences, one requires exactness at all modules except the endpoints. (One might claim that the definition in the book covers these cases, because the "$\dots$" at the beginning and end of the sequence aren't assumed to be infinite and because "exact at an endpoint" doesn't make sense. I think that claim would be quite weak and would need an explanation or at least a comment.)
